# How to access AWS ECR from another account's EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

I have two accounts, `a1` and `a2`.

I have an EC2 instance in a1, `a1.ec2`. It assumes some role in that account, `a1.r`. This role has full access to all ECR actions.

Now, I have an image registry (ECR) in `a2` and would like to be able to access it from `a1.ec2`.

So, I ssh into that instance and in order to test the access I run

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --region <my-region> --registry-id <id of a2>
```

But I get the error

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeRepositories operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<id of a1>:assumed-role/a1.r/i-075fad654b998275c is not authorized to perform: ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource: arn:aws:ecr:*:*:repository/*
```

However, this permission is indeed granted to the role `a1.r`. I verified this by being able to access an ECR in `a1` just fine.

Also, the ECR I like to access has the following permission policies, so I make sure that the trouble is not caused by the ECR of `a2`:

```
    {
      "Sid": "new statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<id of a1>:root"
      },
      "Action": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "new statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<id of a1>:role/a1.r"
      },
      "Action": "*"
    }
```

I had a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/897392/ecr-cross-account-pull-permissions where the solution appears to be to create cross-account roles. Although I could create such a role `a2.cross-acc-r`, I cannot figure out how I can assume that role for the the `aws ecr` cli commands. I do not want the EC2 instance to assume that role, as it resides in a different account (not even sure if that is possible at all).

Am I lacking something basic regarding how AWS IAM works?

Comment: Have you checked this out?
https://serverfault.com/questions/897392/ecr-cross-account-pull-permissions

Comment: Check this out: https://serverfault.com/questions/897392/ecr-cross-account-pull-permissions

Comment: Check this out: https://medium.com/miq-tech-and-analytics/cross-account-how-to-access-aws-container-registry-service-from-another-aws-account-using-iam-b372796ede14

Comment: Check this out from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr/

Comment: Thanks. Your link to serverfault names two answers. The one speaking of defining the ECR policies does not work for me, as stated in my question. For the other answer, I updated my question.

Comment: Regarding your linked medium.com article, Leonard posted and answer and I commented on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pull and push images from one account's EC2 instance into another account's ECR, and do not need the full `aws ecr` CLI functionality, you can do so through docker.
For example, if you want your Jenkins to push built images into ECRs based on the targeted environment (production, staging) residing in different AWS accounts.

Doing so via docker is documented at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr/

Put simply, in the ECR repository, you grant the other account the needed permissions.

Then you get a temporary authentication token to authorize docker towards ECR via:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --registry-ids <account ID> --region <your region> --no-include-email)
```

After this, you can use `docker pull` and `docker push` to access it.

Comment: This works only for primary/secondary accounts? Will that work for totally unrelated AWS accounts?

Comment: Hi @AnatoliiStepaniuk what is the common denominator of those totally unrelated AWS accounts? You can have your ECR repository public, if that is what you are going for. Otherwise, if you want to grant multiple other AWS accounts access, you can set them up just as with a single secondary one.

Comment: Hi, Richard. I added ECR permissions for another "unrelated" account and was able to pull the images this "unrelated" account. So just adding ECR permissions (in the ECR console) was enough.

Comment: `get-login` is not a valid command anymore and get-login-password does not support the flag `--registry-ids`

Answer (score 4):

> I had a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/897392/ecr-cross-account-pull-permissions where the solution appears to be to create cross-account roles. Although I could create such a role `a2.cross-acc-r`, I cannot figure out how I can assume that role for the `aws ecr` CLI commands. I do not want the EC2 instance to assume that role, as it resides in a different account (not even sure if that is possible at all).

You can do that by following the steps below:

1. In **account A**, I created a **role** (e.g `RoleForB`) to trust **account B**, and attach to the before created role an **IAM policy** to allow it to perform some read operations in the **account A**. `e.g ReadOnlyAccess`
2. In **account B**, I created a **role** (e.g `AssumeRoleInA`) and attach a **policy** to allow it to assume the role that is created in **account A**.
3. In **account B** Associate to your EC2 instance `ec2-profile` the IAM role (`AssumeRoleInA`) which was created in step 2.
4. In **account B** login into this EC2 instance to **assume the role** in **Account A** using the command `aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB" --role-session-name "EC2FromB"`.
5. In **account B** EC2 terminal when the command is **step 4.** finished, you can see the **access key ID, secret access key, and session token** from wherever you've routed it, in our case `stdout` either manually or by using a script. You can then assign these values to environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`)

So Let’s check the configurations mentioned above step by step but with some mode detail:

1. As before presented in **account A**, it builds the trust to **account B** by creating the role named `RoleForB` and attaching `ReadOnlyAccess` permission to it.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B_ID:root"},
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

2. In **account B**, create a **role** named `AssumeRoleInA` then attach the corresponding `policy` to allow it to assume the role named `RoleForB` in **account A**.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

3. In **account B**, create a new **EC2 instance** (if it does not exists yet), and associate it's **ec2-profile** with the **IAM role** named `AssumeRoleInA`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

4. In **account B** login into this EC2 instance to **assume the role** in **Account A** using the command:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::Account_A_ID:role/RoleForB" --role-session-name "EC2FromB"`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your `accountA` is my `a2` (with the ECR) and your `accountB` is my `a1` (with the EC2 instance). The trick in your answer seems to be to have the EC2 instance in `a1` assume a role defined in `a2`, right? I will give it a try. Could you maybe minimalize your answer and remove some role, because I do not think that everything is needed that you mentioned.

Comment: Also, can you give me some pointers what to do with the keys? As I just would like to access the ECR via `aws ecr` can I somehow assume the role just temporarily, without storing any keys in the environment? I did not find any commandline parameters for assuming a role.

Comment: @RichardKiefer checkout step 4 for role assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a trust relationship between your account `a1` and `a2`.

From your `a2` Console, go to IAM service, create a new role:

1) Trusted Entity: Another AWS Account (input account `a1`'s ID)

2) Policy: AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser (or others that meet your requirement)

From your `a2` Console, go to ECR service, you need to edit your permission:

```
{
      "Sid": "new statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<id of a1>:root"
      },
      "Action": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "new statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<id of a2>:role/a2.r"
      },
      "Action": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to relate to my given names. This is pretty much what is also suggested in https://medium.com/miq-tech-and-analytics/cross-account-how-to-access-aws-container-registry-service-from-another-aws-account-using-iam-b372796ede14 But logging in to `a1.ec2` which runs with asummed-role `a1.r` (`aOne`!) I still get the same error. Does the EC2 instance need to assume your newly created role `a2.r`?